# Successive minima of a lattice and projection along the the shortest nonzero vector

Tags: nt.number-theory, linear-algebra, lattices

Let $\mathcal L$ be the space of lattices in $\mathbb R^d$. The **$i$-th successive minimum** of $L\in \mathcal L$, denoted $\lambda_i(L)$ is the infimum of the radii of the balls containing $i$-linearly independent vectors in $L$.

Let $v_1$ denote any vector in $L$ with $\lVert v_1\rVert=\lambda_1(L)$. Now project $L$ along $v_1$ onto its orthogonal complement $v_1^{\perp}$. It is easy to see that the projection image of $L$, denoted $L_1$, is again a lattice in the hyperplane $v_1^{\perp}$.

> I speculate that $\lambda_i(L_1) \asymp_d \lambda_{i+1}(L)$.

It is easy to see $\lambda_i(L_1) \le \lambda_{i+1}(L)$ but what about the other direction?

Comment: I guess $\Lambda$ in the second paragraph means $L$?

Comment: @user44172 Yes you are right. Corrected

Comment: If you like my answer, please accept it officially (so that it turns green). Thanks in advance!

Comment: @GHfromMO I upvoted it but I have to take the first answer for fairness.... Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: I see. I did not process the first answer until now :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By taking a shortest lift from $L_1$ to $L$ you obtain that $\lambda_{i+1}(L)\le \lambda_i(L_1)+\frac{1}{2}\lambda_1(L) \le \lambda_i(L_1)+\frac{1}{2}\lambda_{i+1}(L)$. This gives $\frac{1}{2}\lambda_{i+1}(L) \le \lambda_i(L_1)$, i.e. $\lambda_{i+1}(L) \le 2\lambda_i(L_1)$.

Comment: How do you get $\lambda_{i+1}(L)\le \lambda_i(L_1)+\frac{1}{2}$? (I know where that $1/2$ come from so you don't have to explain that part.) Namely how do you guarantee the target you lift to contribute to $\lambda_{i+1}(L)$? "Shortest" doesn't necessarily mean it would be the $i+1$ st successive minima in $L$

Comment: It does not have to be exactly the $i+1$-th minimum. But since you have $i$ independent vectors in $L_1$, you get $i+1$ independent vectors in $L$. So their lengths are upper bounds for the successive minima of $L$.

Answer (score 2):

By [Minkowski's second theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski%27s_second_theorem), we have
$$\prod_{i=1}^{d-1}\frac{\lambda_{i+1}(L)}{\lambda_i(L_1)}\asymp_d\frac{\mathrm{covol}(L)/\|v_1\|}{\mathrm{covol}(L_1)}=1.$$
The factors on the left-hand side are at least $1$, hence they are individually $\ll_d 1$.